# Regular expression to split on special character preceded or followed by a space in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and am having trouble with a regular expression I'm using to parse an external file into individual words in a list.  I have to be able to correctly insert contractions like "don't" and hyphenated words like "x-ray".

I actually have two things not working properly: 1) My list inserts an empty string for the last element and 2) when attempting to split on a single quote or hyphen (either preceded or followed by a space), it splits on the special character no matter what is next to it.

I thought you could put characters in parenthesis to say "this followed by this" but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code snippet:

```
with open(badWords, 'r') as f:
        line = f.read().strip()
        ignoreList = split(r'[(\s\') (\'\s) (\s\-) (\-\s) \. \! \; \: \" \$ \% \& \, \+ \* \< \> \? \/ \[ \] \( \) \d]+', line)
```

The output of the file (where "don't" and "x-ray" were added) looks like:

> ['Four', 'score', 'and', 'don', 't', 'x', 'ray', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'father', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation', 'conceived', 'in', 'Liberty', 'dedicated', 'to', 'the', 'proposition', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal', '']

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact contents of the file and what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be:
['Four', 'score', 'and', "don't", 'x-ray', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'father', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation', 'conceived', 'in', 'Liberty', 'dedicated', 'to', 'the', 'proposition', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal']

And if it wasn't obvious, I'm required to use regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, but what is the input? It's kinda hard to create the output, without knowing the input.

Comment: **WHAT'S THE INPUT? again...**

Comment: I assume `"Four score and don't x-ray seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal."`, as it's kind of famous (except for the inserted words). Although, not everyone here is equally acquainted with American history and culture.

Comment: "I thought you could put characters in parenthesis to say "this followed by this" but it doesn't seem to work." - basically yes, but not inside a character class, `[...]`. You might need to learn regular expressions again [from scratch](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), as it seems you have some misunderstanding on very basic levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone in a different direction to accommodate other requirements of the assignment and wanted to share the results.

The other requirement is to load the words into a dictionary and count the occurrences so I've had to define a pattern that can be reused in a loop.  I'm matching on at least one letter, followed by 0 or 1 of either the single quote (for contractions) or a hyphen (for hyphenated words), followed by at least one letter.

```
pattern = compile("[a-z]+[-']?[a-z]+", IGNORECASE)
wordCount = {}
with open('Words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for word in f.read().split():
        match = search(pattern, word)
        if match:
            if match.group().lower() not in wordCount:
                wordCount[match.group().lower()] = 1
            else:
                wordCount[match.group().lower()] += 1
```

There might be more elegant ways to get these results but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is how to split all words and include hyphenated or apostropied words correctly.

Try this regex:  [^\s.\?!]+

Add other punctuation to ignore as needed.

Example - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MHa11L/2)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you want to do with cases where there is a space next to a hyphen or apostrophe.

Assume the text is `"Is X-ray a hyper- or a hyponym of scanner, darlin'?`

If you intend the result to be `["Is", "X-ray", "a", "hyper-", "or", "a", "hyponym", of "scanner", "darlin'"]`, it is easy, as we simply split on a sequence of anything that's not a letter, a hyphen or an apostrophe:

```
split(r"[^a-zA-Z-']+", line)
```

If you imagine the result to be `["Is", "X-ray", "a", "hyper", "or", "a", "hyponym", of "scanner", "darlin"]`, then it gets a bit more complex:

```
split(r"\s+['-]\s*|['-]\s+|[^a-zA-Z-']+", line)
```

Here we split on everything we split on before, but also sequences of spaces followed by a hyphen or an apostrophe (possibly followed by more spaces), or just a hyphen or an apostrophe followed by spaces, but without a space in front (basically saying there has to be spaces in front or in back or both).

Comment: The second one is what I'm after though I still get an empty string added as the last element of the list.  So `"from the earth."` returns `['from', 'the', 'earth', '']`.  Thanks!

Comment: That is inevitable if you are using `split` if you have delimiter (in your case, `"."`) at the start or at the end of the string. You can just remove empty ones: `[word for word in words if word != '']`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Amadan!